# Count in the SUM SQL

Tags: sql, count, sum

I have the sql function like the following:

```
SELECT
    SUM(3 * tb_spp.bulanan_spp ),
    COUNT(tb_bulan.id) AS JUMLAH, 
    SUM( count(tb_bulan.id) * tb_angsuran_spp.nominal_spp ), 
SUM( (3 * tb_spp.bulanan_spp) - (3 * tb_angsuran_spp.nominal_spp) ) as SPP 
FROM tb_spp, tb_angsuran_spp, tb_bulan 
where tb_spp.id_siswa = tb_angsuran_spp.id_siswa and tb_spp.id_siswa = '1' 
and tb_bulan.id = tb_angsuran_spp.id_bulan 
and tb_bulan.id between '1' and '2'
```

But when i run the error message appears '# 1111 - Invalid use of group function'

What is the cause and how is the solution?

Comment: This query is full of problems.  You can start by telling us which database you are using.

Comment: After i check wrong is command 'SUM (count (tb_bulan.id) * tb_angsuran_spp.nominal_spp)' how should it be?

Answer (score 0):

`sum(count())` isn't generally allowed.  There are a few other changes I would make to the query as well:

```
SELECT SUM( 3 * s.bulanan_spp ),
       count(b.id) as JUMLAH, 
       SUM(a.nominal_spp ), 
       SUM( (3 * s.bulanan_spp) - (3 * a.nominal_spp) ) as SPP 
FROM tb_spp s JOIN
     tb_angsuran_spp a
     on s.id_siswa = a.id_siswa join
     tb_bulan b
     on b.id = a.id_bulan 
where s.id_siswa = 1 and 
      b.id between 1 and 2;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Ids are usually numbers; hence I removed the single quotes (they are appropriate for strings).

I'm not sure that  your sums and counts will produce correct answers. If not, ask *another* question, including sample data and desired results.  This answer addresses the syntax problems in this question.